# How to query list of EMPTY bucket names in Android

Tags: android, mediastore

I'd like to find all MediaStore buckets, including the ones that don't have any photos in them. All solutions, posted on SO, query for photos and then extract bucket names, but since the bucket is empty, there are no photos that will be returned by the query for that particular bucket. The Gallery App itself does not show empty Buckets/Folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BUCKET_ID` is a property of the any media based on what provider considers as a media. `BUCKET_ID` is automatically computed from the `DATA` column of `MediaStore.MediaColumns`. `DATA` is path to the file on disk.
So if there is no media in the directory there will be no `DATA` and as the result no `BUCKET_ID` property creation happens.

If you need to distinguish between empty and non-empty buckets by a property that they have in common, use their path `file.getPath()` as each directory has a unique path.

Imagine you have 10 directory on your device that have media inside them while maybe there are more than 1000 non-media contained directories on your device. So it is illogical if android search through all the existing directories on your device each time you query your `MediaStore`.

So the reason behind not assigning ids to empty directories from android is searching through ids of directories that have media inside them which is much faster, as the purpose of `MediaStore` is faster access to 'only media' files.

Comment: is the 10 media directory limit somewhere documented? I've pretty much did my implementation similar to what you've described, but I've been able to create more than 10 directories in the PICTURES directory and once images were placed into them, the MediaStore was generating proper BUCKET_IDs.

Comment: `is the 10 media directory limit somewhere documented?` Edited my third paragraph. No this 10 number is just an imaginary example for ease of explanation.